# object.className or object.getAttribute("className/class")?

Tags: javascript, classname

Between both those :

### Javascript

```
function setCss(object, css) {
    return (object.className = css);
}
function getCss(object, css) {
    return object.className;
}
```

### Or

```
function getCss2(object)
{   
    if (object.getAttribute("className")) {
        return object.getAttribute("className");
    }
    return object.getAttribute("class");
}


function setCss2(object, cssclass)
{        
    if (object.getAttribute("className")) {
        return object.setAttribute("className",cssclass);
    }
    object.setAttribute("class",cssclass);
}
```

### HTML

```
<a href="#" onClick="setCss(this, 'newclass')" />
<a href="#" class="something" onClick="alert(getCss(this))" />
<a href="#" onClick="setCss2(this, 'newclass')" />
<a href="#" class="something" onClick="alert(getCss2(this))" />
```

Both version seems to work in IE8, FF4, Chrome, Opera and Safari. ([jsFiddle (improved) demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7dyzK/))

**Which one is best-usage practice and why?** Did you ever run into any issue with either version?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`getAttribute("class")` is more universal, because it can be used in different types of documents. In XML documents, most importantly. Including SVG.

`element.className` works only in HTML. It is described in the [DOM level 2 HTML specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-95362176).

Answer (score 10):

`object.getAttribute("className");` actually does not work.

The difference is that `getAttribute` gets the value of a *HTML attribute* as it is written in the HTML code (with some exceptions).

These values are mostly also the initial values of the *properties of the DOM element*. But accessing them can yield different values, due to pre-/postprocessing.

For example, if you have an `<a>` element, `el.href` gives you the complete (absolute) URL, while `el.getAttribute('href')` gives you the URL as it was written in the HTML.

Most of the time, you want to access the  properties of the DOM element, as these reflect the current state of the element.

Comment: It will work in IE 8 Quirks Mode and below since their implementation only takes DOM property names for get/set/removeAttribute. Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536739%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: `object.getAttribute("className");` is required for IE 7 and less actually. You can easily guess why... :/

Comment: @Kraz: I see... then lets say in *proper* implementations, this does not work ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use the first one.

It's sorter. It works in every browser even the very old ones that don't support getAttribute. It probably faster too.

But please don't use a function for this. Just use this.className and this.className='newClass'. Using a function is overkill for this.

Answer (score 0):

According to MDN Webdocs its better to use setAttribute/getAttribute, because `element.className` is not always the string of classes. In case that your `element` is a SVG path, `element.className` will suddenly be an instance of a  [SVGAnimatedString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGAnimatedString):

> className can also be an instance of SVGAnimatedString if the element is an SVGElement. **It is better to get/set the className of an**
> **element using Element.getAttribute and Element.setAttribute** if you are
> dealing with SVG elements. However, take into account that
> Element.getAttribute returns null instead of "" if the element has an
> empty class attribute.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className#notes